# curl login into website not working

Tags: php, curl

i have a code to login into website. It works on site like wordpress, but in site i want to login nothing happens. Where is no error message or anything. 
here is my code:

```
<?php
print" <head>
        <base href='http://www.example.com/'/>
    </head>";

$url = 'http://www.example.com/login.php?';                        
$postdata = 'username=dasds&password=frkm'; 
$referer = $url; 
$cookie = "cookie.txt" ;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
print $result;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and their html form:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/login.php">
<label class="registration" for="username">
<span>Username</span>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30"/>
</label>
<label class="registration" for="password">
<span>Password</span>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password"/>
</label>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**:

- Drop the trailing ? in the URL.
- Specify both `COOKIEJAR` and `COOKIEFILE` and set an absolute path to the cookie file:

**CODE**:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/'.$cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/'.$cookie);
```

And:

- Load the home-page once before attempting to login to get any cookies they might give you.
- Make sure not captchas are involved. Track the POST process in a browser (FireFox + HttpFox).

If you track the login requests + responses in the browser, you can't fail.